# iOS how to start the image picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIButton` and when the user clicks it, I want to start the image picker controller

I already configure what I think it is enough but I couldn't know what is the message that I have to pass to that image picker to start working

This is my code

```
#import "ImagePickerViewController.h"

@interface ImagePickerViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;


@end

@implementation ImagePickerViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (IBAction)SelectImage:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

@end
```

I have already set the correct protocols:

```
@interface ImagePickerViewController : UIViewController < UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present the `UIImagePicker`

```
- (IBAction)SelectImage:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why you put `nil` in completion ? in completion I would like to put the selected image in an image view. or is there another message from `uiimageviewcontrollerdelegate` I should use for that case ?

Comment: @CarolSmith: You need to use `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` delegate for getting the picked image

Answer (score 1):

You can show the picker with:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

And then in your delegate callback `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` you get the image and dismiss the picker again:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
      UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; 
      [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your view controller class to show the UIImagePickerController.

Simply use

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will present it modally. If you are running on an iPad, you instead have to present it in a popover controller, as follows:

Declare a new property in the @interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController* imagePickerPopover;
```

Present the popover controller e.g:

```
UIButton* button = sender;
self.imagePickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePicker];
[self.imagePickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```